# AWS Lambda function url call gives 502 Bad gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm getting started with AWS lambda and created a basic java handler like below.

```java
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import java.util.Map;

// Handler value: example.Handler
public class Handler implements RequestHandler<Map<String,String>, String>{
  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
  @Override
  public String handleRequest(Map<String,String> event, Context context)
  {
    LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
    String response = "200 OK";
    // log execution details
    logger.log("ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES: " + gson.toJson(System.getenv()));
    logger.log("CONTEXT: " + gson.toJson(context));
    // process event
    logger.log("EVENT: " + gson.toJson(event));
    logger.log("EVENT TYPE: " + event.getClass());
    return response;
  }
}
```

When I'm testing the lambda function via AWS portal, it is working fine. But when I'm triggering the same using function URL like below, I'm getting a `502: Bad Gateway` error.

```bash
    curl --location --request POST 'https://xyz.lambda-url.region.on.aws?message=HelloWorld' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data-raw '{
        "some-key": "some-value"
    }'
```

> An error occurred during JSON parsing: java.lang.RuntimeException
> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred during JSON parsing
> Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
> at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 84] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["headers"])
> at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.serialization.factories.JacksonFactory$InternalSerializer.fromJson(JacksonFactory.java:184)
> Caused by: com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
> at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 84] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["headers"])

I've mentioned the Auth type of Function URL to `NONE` as well. Is there anything I'm missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might because you are using GET instead of POST and the request body might be getting ignored leading to the event object being empty or invalid

Comment: @VikramS, that was a bug in the post. I am actually using POST request.

Comment: I feel the RequestHandler<Map<String,String> shouldnt be String, String as the Lambda is receiving the request similar to the API Gateway request with headers and body.

Comment: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/blob/main/sample-apps/java-events/src/main/java/example/HandlerApiGateway.java Try this sample

Comment: @VikramS, when I'm making `GET` calls instead of `POST` calls, cloudwatch is not showing log streams even though I'm getting a 200 response. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 2):

According to [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-auth.html), even though you specify AuthType as NONE, your function's resource-based policy is always in effect and must grant public access before your function URL can receive requests.

You can re-verify your lambda role policy if it has public access and also with AuthType set to NONE.